# Undefined Offset: 0

Tags: php, json, undefined, offset, steam

Working with JSON in PHP and that error keeps popping up.The PHP code I'm using is

```
echo $JSON["response"]["players"][0]["steamid"];
```

The actual JSON is right [here.](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=EZ02RYad) The var dump is

`array(1) { ["response"]=> array(1) { ["players"]=> array(0) { } } }`

[I used an online JSON viewer and it looks just fine to me.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1HB04.png)

Anybody got any ideas?

Comment: Player has no index, is empty

Comment: $JSON["response"]["players"][0]["steamid"]; does not exist.

Comment: players is empty. so there is no index 0. 0 would be the first element.

Comment: Snip. The problem was with the request to get the JSON. It was a bad request, so the players array was empty. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1):

By default, [`json_decode`](http://php.net/json_decode) will decode objects as `stdClass` instances that do not implement `ArrayAccess`.  Your code should probably emit an error.  You should actually be using:

```
$JSON->response->players[0]->steamid;
```

You could also use `true` for the second argument of `json_decode`.

This works with the JSON provided in your link, but the `var_dump` seems to indicate that the JSON in the link is not the same JSON that the PHP script is acquiring.  Make sure that you are using the correct parameters to get this JSON remotely.